# Zipalign file giving this error

Tags: zipalign

[image: Hi I am downloading zip align from developer website.when I am clicking the Zip-Align it giving the below error]

can any one please help me with this issue.

Comment: Have you tried to do what the error message tells you to do?

Comment: what i will do I am not getting?

Comment: Download the .NET Framework in the required version from Microsoft and install it...